# What does the following line in PostgreSQL mean?

Tags: postgresql

I am analyzing an SQL function that was written by my predecessor, and came across the following line at the end of a `for i in 1...` loop:

```
array[i] := '#.' || array[i]
```

I don't understand the query enough yet to provide context, this is one of the puzzle pieces that I am trying to solve.

It is part of this function:

Function to transpose data so that each identifier appears on 1 line.

```sql
create or replace function transposeTable(
    out_table_name varchar,                     -- Temporary table that will save the output (result).
    in_table_name varchar,                      -- Table from which the data will be pulled.
    in_id_column_name varchar,                  -- Name of the ID column (SSID).
    in_cols_to_use_for_transpose varchar[],     -- Name of the columns (from in_table_name) to use for the transpose.
                                                -- ... Data from these columns will be filled into the new columns
                                                -- ... "PrefixA 1", "Prefix B 1", ... "Prefix A 2", "Prefix B 2", ...
    in_transpose_order_by_column_name varchar,  -- The column which will be used to make sure "PrefixA 1", "PrefixB 1", ...
                                                -- ... "PrefixZ 1" are referencing the same procedure data.
    in_prefixes varchar[]                       -- List of prefixes that will be used in the transposed table
                                                -- ... (Procedure , Dosis , ...)
) returns void as $$
    declare
        query varchar;
        i integer;
        num_prefixes integer;
    begin

        -- Construct a query that will return the input table, along with an extra
        -- column, containing the "PrefixA 1", "PrefixB 1", ...
        query := '';

        num_prefixes = array_length(in_prefixes, 1);

        for i in 1..num_prefixes loop
            if i > 1 then
                query := query || E' \nUNION ALL \n';
            end if;

            query := query || 'select *, ';
            query := query || 'concat_ws ('''', ''' || in_prefixes[i] || ''', ';
            query := query || 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ';
            query := query || 'PARTITION BY ' || colname(in_id_column_name) || ' ORDER BY ' || colname(in_transpose_order_by_column_name);
            query := query || ')) AS thecols';
            query := query || ', concat_ws('''', ''' || i::text || ''', '''') AS theorder '; 
            query := query || 'from ' || in_table_name;
            in_cols_to_use_for_transpose[i] := '#.' || in_cols_to_use_for_transpose[i];
        end loop;

        -- Use the colpivot function (defined above) to transpose the given query.
        -- The result will be saved in a temporary table with the same name as out_table_name.
        perform colpivot(out_table_name, query, array[in_id_column_name], in_prefixes, in_cols_to_use_for_transpose);

        return;
```

Comment: The string `#.` gets prepended to the i-th element of an array.

Comment: Right, but what would be the point in doing this? Does #. Mean something?

Comment: How should I guess that without seeing the rest of the code?

Comment: My bad, I was hoping that maybe it would mean something by itself. I added the function in my original comment!

Answer (score 1):

It is the standard [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in SQL.

Each value in array now has a `'#.'` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks! And does this "#." mean something? I am not sure what the point of this line is. I have added the function in my original comment for more context.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what the `colpivot` function does.